# Accessing char pointer in structure

Tags: c++, linux

```
typedef struct fred {
  char mytype[41];
  char* myremark;
} fred_t;
```

With an instance of that structure

```
fred_t* mystruct;
```

I can print mytype

```
fprintf (stdout, "%s\n", mystruct->mytype);
```

but I am failing to get the syntax to print myremark in a similar way.

(It's old code that I'm modifying.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the instance has been correctly initialized (i.e. the `myremark` points to a valid string), you can print it in the exact same manner.

By the way, to print a string to `stdout` you can simply use `puts`:

```
puts(mystruct->mytype);
puts(mystruct->myremark);
```

Comment: Please can you explain why. mystruct->mytype is [*mystruct].mytype, which is char. myystruct->myremark is [*mystruct].myremark which is a pointer to char

Comment: `mytype` is not a `char` (which would be a single character), it's an *array* of char, which, when passed to a function such as `puts` or `fprintf`, decays to a `char *`. Keep in mind that in C a `char` pointer/array is a string. The fundamental difference between the two members is that the space in memory for `mytype` is in the structure itself, while the space of the string pointed by `myremark` is somewhere else (probably in the heap).

Comment: Treating them both the same leads to success with mytype but signal 11 with myremark. Does that indicate that it may never have been populated ie an absence of null terminators

Comment: It may also indicate that `myremark` is set to `NULL` (which probably means that there's no remark); try to check this first before printing (`if(mystruct->myremark!=NULL) puts(mystruct->myremark); else puts("No remark");`).

Comment: Matteo - Thank you very much - you have given enough to get going again having been stuck for hours.

Comment: @Mike: no problem, but if you have this kind of problems with arrays and pointers I'd suggest you to have a look at a C manual. `:)`

Comment: The API I'm interfacing with is under documented. Eventually I found a similar exmple in an unrelated bit of sample code. There was a two stage process the first stage identified the instance of the structure, but the memory pointed to by the char* pointer wasn't populated until after a second API call referencing the identied structure (efficient as is only gets what the user wants) I'm not sure which chapter of a Beginner Guide to C I'd find that in :-). Apolgies for my lazy description of the problem and thank you again for you help.

Comment: @Mke: sorry, I thought the problem was with the usual pointer/array beginner confusion and not with the library you're working with. Glad you solved anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

`myremark` is just a pointer.  It's not pointing to anything and, from the looks of it, is not initialized either so you're just going to get some random block of memory.

`mytype` has allocated storage (41 bytes, to be precise), and so you get the desired result.  `myremark` points to nothing.

Comment: I've simplified the structure from a more complex one. It's populated by a other calls to an API. There's someting there I just can't prin it.

Comment: @Mike, can you paste more code then?  You've simplified it down to the point where it is difficult to tell what is wrong, if it is not the case that the pointer is just not pointing to anything as your original question infers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf (stdout, "%s\n", mystruct->myremark);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fprintf (stdout, "%s\n", mystruct->myremark);` should work if `myremark` is properly NULL terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the %s modifier just like you are doing for the array.  I am wondering if you ever initialize `myremark` to point to a valid string.

Answer (score 0):

The API I'm interfacing with is under documented. Each call is simply documented but there is little guidance on how eveything hangs toghether. There is a small collection of example code. Eventually I found a similar example in an unrelated bit of sample code by searching on "vector" (don't ask). There was a two stage process the first stage identified the instance of the structure, but the memory pointed to by the char* pointer wasn't populated until after a second API call referencing the already identifed structure (efficient as is only gets what the user wants - which is much bigger than the simplified illustration I presented). I was missing this second call.

Almost every one who answered asked whether the pointer pointed to an actual string. They were all right and no matter how I changed my syntax it wasn't going to find anything until after that 2nd call. Thanks to all who replied